# AG-grid only selecting records up to 20

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am facing one issue on UI module related to ag-grid rows selection.
I am doing an excel upload which renders rows in dashboard and also it selects(checkbox) the recently uploaded rows.
Post that I am doing validation of selected rows using validate button, but its only validating first 20 rows. But when I scroll down till last row and then clicks on validate, it's working fine and able to validate all selected rows.

Please let me know the possible cause of the issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idon't know exactly what's the issue but it is clearly a problem with agGrid rendering rows based on the current scroll position.

a workaround is to force the selection of all rows via the API. not sure if it will bypass this issue but here how to do it :

```
gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
      node.setSelected(true);
    });
```

Another thing you might try is to increase the row buffer with the `cacheBlockSize` attribute. if you are using pagination, you can set it to the current page size like 50 or 100. in fairness I think this is the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, using pagination alongwith row buffer solve the issue.